# Token based authentication and multiple sessions

Tags: authentication, session, authorization

I've a token based authentication system (REST) that I inherited for an iOS app (can't change), and I've to re-use the same authentication web api system (that I can change to adapt for the web requests while still accommodating iOS app).

Here's how the authentication system works.

1. username, password -> if valid a token is returned to the user and also saved to the database
2. getNewToken -> passes the old authToken, web api verifies from the table, issues a new token, updates the database table

1 is triggered by user login while 2 is automated interval based call every 15 minutes by the iOS app (I guess to keep the session alive, like heart beat)

Now when user is on the web and logs in, I call #1 to get the token but then if user is already on the device, the old token at device won't work because it got updated on the server as a result of user signing on the web.

This makes me wonder and in the light of above scenario my question is how multiple sessions are handled using authentication token system out there in real life, for instance I could open gmail or Facebook in two different browsers and both sessions are maintained (I'm not sure if they are using token based system or some other but let's say they are for an example). Please advise.

Comment: You need to manage login tokens per user + device and not per user only.

Comment: I see, so I guess I've to introduce another table, let's say token(id, authenticationToken, user_id), where user_id is the foreign key to the user table, and manage sessions from there, please confirm.

Comment: Yes if id is id of the device cause you need to store device id in some place. If you can install programs on the server better to store login tokens not in database but in some external key value storage like redis or memcached, if you can do it of course.

Comment: ah, no, the id was PK AI, in that case table would be token(id, deviceId, authenticationToken, user_id), please enlighten more on the deviceId, where do I get this deviceId (both for browser and iOS app) information. I like the idea of key value storage, I can use mongodb

Comment: Mongodb stores data on disks and not in memory, so it is litle bit slower than Redis. Another benefit of using redis is ability to define key lifetime, it means that you can kill ghost keys without coding, but mongodb is good too just remember that you going to have many tokens that not in use. Key may be your login token. Device id of android or ios can be generated on the device, it can be some guid for example, on android exists android id that is unique string. And you can generate some id for browser on login and to store it in cookie.

Comment: We have some system that generates token to anybody who logins even without device id, it gives us less statistics and less ability to understand what happens, but it was done on base of existing clients that cannot generate device id

Comment: Mostly device id required to relogin from same device, than you can to recognize that user already has record and to update it.

Comment: awesome... :) I understand benefit of redis now. you can copy paste all into an answer, that helped. will comment if I'm still missing a piece.

Comment: also if you can add some stuff on security, I don't have SSL right now so that means anyone in the middle can pick this token and device_id and pretend to be the user. So I should get an ssl?

Comment: Definitely ssl will improve security dramatically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if id is id of the device cause you need to store device id in some place. If you can install programs on the server better to store login tokens not in database but in some external key value storage like redis or memcached, if you can do it of course.

Comment: question, what do I use device_id for when it comes to statistics? it's going to be some guid that I won't be able to understand, second do I've to check on the server that both device_id and token matches to retrieve user_id

Comment: I'm studying more on REDIS, and going to implement it, can you please help. so I'm going to have authToken, user_id as key value pair, tokens['abc'] = 1, tokens['def'] = 2, tokens['xyz'] = 3, wondering where device_id comes in this picture for the key/value pair

Comment: Device id for example can show you how long user uses your program from same device, or how many devices has the user. In REDIS you can store data this way - key is your authtoken and value some complex data about the login. It may be some data like device id, user first name and... Value can be stored as, for example, json string that you can deserialize or some binary data. It may work this way: request coming -> get authtoken from that request -> find record in redis by authkey -> if record exists deserialize value. Then on output you will hold base data about user without querying database

Comment: Thanks man for changing my whole perspective about things, I learned redis and changed my nodejs code overnight, and all my token based authentications are going through redis. Only hitting the database for username/password. auth validation responses are amazing under 10ms, managing authToken in the db was pain, for every renew of token, I'm deleting the old one (learned from twitter toy clone in php)

Comment: however, in your earlier comments when you said ghost keys, scenario 1 -> iOS app is logged in all the time, if logout I'll delete the auth key on redis, same with browser end. save the token in local storage and renew when website was accessed to ensure login validity. my question is when is the case when I'll end up with too many ghost keys?

Comment: For example somebody can to reinstall application on iOS without logout, deleting browser cache, using different browsers on same computer. It always exists ghost keys no meter what you do. But if you configure lifetime of the key in redis you can solve this problem (at least partially). In my last project I am extending this lifetime every time user starts session on the site. It means that if user not browse to the site for some period of time login token deleted from redis automatically. On iOS for example you can send renew command each time user opens program.

Comment: I see, and how much time did you configure the lifetime for the key in your last project?

Comment: also I've a feeling that sites like for example twitter are storing everything in the redis, following, followers including posts. Is that the way everyone's heading right now and not using database anymore?

Comment: I have configured lifetime fot 2 weeks cause in our particular case it was the maximum. But it is really depended on project. You can not stay without database, it still will be the main data storage especially when exists so many data like in twitter. I believe that they loading partially data to memory when user connected, but all data saved in some database.

Comment: And even with relational databases it can be quick response times, for example at this moment I can find posts by tag or list of tags in table with 20 million records in less than 50 milliseconds. With filter by 1 additional parameter that is list too and order by.

Comment: awesome man. Thanks for your input, it has been helpful.

Comment: another question man :) I've both admin and standard users (only key/value pairs no hash), the authentication system is same for both. For admin authentication, I'm setting the key as `key:admin` = `user_id`, and for standard user `key` = `user_id`, to avoid letting the standard user, if he's logged in already to access the /admin pieces, that's all I can think of, any better strategy?

Comment: May be I am did not understand right, only to emphasize, It is prohibited to store any user data related to login on client except of some key that should not include (again) any login data or user role and etc... All data of this kind have to be stored on the server. So the strategy can be - to store key / value pair where the key some login key that user got from the server and value is user data. User sends you key in all requests and you retrieves user from Radis on base of this key. Which language do you use for programming? Maybe I can show you some code or pseudo code.

Comment: ah, let me clear, I'm not storing `user_id` at client, client only has the key. Let's say client saves the key `'abc'`. On the server (nodejs) I'm saving `'abc:admin' => 101`. and for standard user `'xyz' => 102`

Comment: the authentication system is shared between the client and the server, so if route is /admin I check if `key:admin` exists (on the server, not client), I'm wondering if `key:admin` is good or is there a better way

Comment: key:admin may work, but it is strange to me to store data about user in key even on server. Usually required a little bit more information about user than to know admin or not. So all that information maybe stored in **value**. For example **value** may be information that looks this way {"_isAdmin":true, "_roles":[1,2,3], "_firstName":"John", "_lastName":"Doe"}. When the key received you trying to retrieve value by this key, if nothing exists that user not logged in, if data exists you deserializing that data into some object, and from that moment holds all required data.

Comment: Now you know who is the users, is that user admin and administration roles of the user or any information you need to know about the user. And it may be done in any route not only /admin.

Comment: I guess, `key=>value` type only accepts single value, for instance `SET connections 10`, I can't execute the command `set "somekey" {"_isAdmin": true }` (tried on http://try.redis.io/) unless I use hashes, I was using key/value to lookup users via tokens (multiple tokens)

Comment: OR I should be using hashes?

Comment: This way it will work: set "somekey" "{\"_isAdmin\":true}" in  try.redis.io. In Redis on my computer this works too "somekey" "{\"_isAdmin\": true }" - with spaces before and after true

Comment: Usually if I want to create some JSON represented as string I use JSON.NET serializer or protobuf-net as binary serializer. Here you can find supported by Redis data types  http://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: hey @genichm revisiting this thread, a little update, I'm using jwt.io, creating a token with payload and sending it back to the client, and then I verify and get the data back, this way I don't have to use redis or memcache, please advise.